# WPF expander expanding/collapsing

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls, expander

Hey all I am trying to figure out why my expander does not expand the second time I click on it. In other words, when I click the first time and it expands, click the second time and it collapses and then click it for the 3rd time, it doesn't open.

I have an expander and inside that expander is a textbox. This is the code I use to open it and close it:

```
Private Sub expanderFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ticketCurrentExpander = sender

    ticketCurrentTextBox = ticketMyTextBoxes(textBoxNum)
    ticketCurrentExpander.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
    ticketCurrentExpander.Height = 250
    ticketCurrentExpander.IsExpanded = True
    Canvas.SetZIndex(ticketCurrentExpander, 1000)
End Sub

Private Sub expanderLostFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    ticketCurrentExpander.IsExpanded = False
    ticketCurrentExpander.Height = 24
    Canvas.SetZIndex(ticketCurrentExpander, 0)
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

I found out that the **height** property is the cause of the issue of it not showing up the 3rd time when clicking. I have not figured out how to show it without having to define the height of the box. If I do not specify the height then the box never opens at all when I click on it.

What would i be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you exactly what your problem is, or if it is even reproducible from your code example, but I can tell you that there is a simpler way to control the opening and closing of an `Expander` control. If you data bind the `Expander.IsExpanded` property to a `bool` property in your view model, then you can open and close the `Expander` by setting the property as and when you feel like it.

See this basic example, which swaps the mentioned `bool` property for the `IsChecked` property of a `ToggleButton` for simplicity:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Expander Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBox Text="Enter something here" />
        <Expander.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                        ElementName=ToggleButton}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Expander.Style>
    </Expander>
    <ToggleButton Name="ToggleButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="Open/Close Expander" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: But doesn't this req. a checkbox?

Comment: I said *See this basic example, **which swaps the mentioned bool property for the `IsChecked` property of a `ToggleButton`** for simplicity*... so no, you don't need a `Checkbox`, `ToggleButton`, or any other control. You just need a `bool` property in your view model/code behind.